# What to do when bluetooth is unauthorized?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing a flutter app that requires bluetooth. If bluetooth does not work, the app das no purpose.

I am using the library [flutter_reactive_ble](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble).

This library communicates the status of the device bluetooth using the [BleStatus](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_reactive_ble/latest/flutter_reactive_ble/BleStatus-class.html) enum.

The potential values are as follows...

```
poweredOff
ready
unauthorized
unknown
unsupported
```

I am trying to determime my course of action for each of these status. For example...

```
poweredOff - tell user to turn on bluetooth
ready - good to go
unauthorized - ??
unknown - keep waiting till determined
unsupported - tell user app won't work on their device
```

I am not quite sure what to do on unauthorized. I am also not quite sure what unauthorized means. Does this mean that the app did not set the right permission at the platform level? For example, maybe the dev did not add the right permissions to AndroidManifest.xml. Or does it mean that I have to prompt the user to accept some permissions?

Answer (score 1):

By refering to the package's documentation `BleStatus.unauthorized` means that bluetooth usage is not authorized for this application which means that the user refuses the bluetooth permission when it was asked.

You could ask your user to authorize bluetooth usage for the application in its phone's settings.